# Wordpress keeps truncating my feeds and I can't stop it

Tags: rss, feed

I have a little problem with my self hosted wordpress blog.
the problem is it keeps truncating my feeds even when I have chosen not to in the settings page.
one thing to bear in mind is that I use `<!--more-->` tag in almost all of my posts. I was wondering if it's because of that or something else?!
any help would be awesome.
thanks

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed that might be touching your feeds?

Comment: @Manzabar I don't think so. I even installed the `Full Text Feed` plugin but it doesn't do any good!

Comment: According to Full Text Feed's homepage, that plugin isn't needed in WordPress 2.5 (and presumably past that). You are running the lastest version of WordPress (3.2.1), right? Also, if you're not sure about plugins altering your feed, consider disabling all of them and then recheck your feed.

Comment: I have disabled all the plugins and still the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you check the page source of your feed - some browsers will not show the full feed when looking at it raw (as the plain XML file) when using your browser to view http://yourdomain/feed

If you look at the raw source the full text should be found in under the "content" tag - Firefox for example will only show the "title" "link" and "description" but hide the content. IE will show the full feed in the browser.

Also make sure the full feed is set in the wordpress settings

Answer (score 0):

Could also be something your theme is doing.  Does you theme have an options panel, with an option related to RSS feeds?